# Android Application: Run code on a timer from the background

Tags: java, android, timer, notifications, background-process

hello everyone and thank you in advance.  My problem is that I have an app that the user will start in the foreground and will set a variable as a timer.  The user will most likely close that app, or the phone will go to sleep. So I need the app to background and then run code to send a notification when that timer hits 0.

For the timer I would use unix time and have the background process check to see if it matched or the current time surpassed when the timer goes off.

I would like to know - A) how to send the app to the background with these instructions
B) how to then foreground the app, or at least be able to send a notification after running some code

Again, thank you very much, let me know if I was not clear or if I missed someone's previous thread.

Answer (score 1):

This post should be a good place to start, it looks like what you want to use is a service.

[How to run an android app in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029040/how-to-run-an-android-app-in-background)

Answer (score 1):

Look at extending the Android [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class to create a custom Handler that creates a [notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) when the Handler receives a [Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) that you send it using the method `sendMessageAtTime(android.os.Message, long uptimeMillis)` or `sendMessageDelayed(android.os.Message, long delayMillis)`. When that timer went off could be specified using the `long` parameter of either of those methods.

Hope this helped!