# How to run services even after screen off, Lock the screen?

Tags: android, android-service

In my application am using services move to another activity after ten minutes even the screen in off,screen locked.

my problem Service is run when screen is in **ON** condition,but in screen **OFF** or when lock the screen condition means the service is stopped after i unlock the screen means service start from there.i don't know how to do this thing.Can any one know please help me to solve this problem.

**My service time coding**

```
public class Time_out_services extends Service {

Handler mHandler;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful

    mHandler = new Handler();


    mHandler.postDelayed(first_Task, 4 * 60 * 1000);


    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
  }

Runnable first_Task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        mHandler = new Handler();

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(Time_out_services.this, Dialog_actvity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);      

        stopSelf();
    }
    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Follow this https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Answer (score 2):

you have to register a reciever for the screen on off

```
    private static BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
```

make a method "regScreenReciever()" put this code in that

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
                    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
                    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
                    appContext.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

then create a broadcast reciever , override its onRecieve method  and then put

```
if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
                    Util.disableKeygaurd();
                }
                Intent linkuryIntent = new     Intent(context,UpdateService.class);
                context.startService(linkuryIntent);
```

your code will run fine

Comment: I've posted a pretty clean nifty solution here. Hope it helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029040/how-to-run-an-android-app-in-background/43555050#43555050