# Application exit to keep it in background for some times

Tags: android

I am working on Android app where i using a service to fetch location on a time interval using timer. But if I keep my app in back ground for some time then application exit and its **onCreate()** method is re Called  and my timer stops please tell me how I can keep running my application for long times.

```
timer  = new Timer();
timerTask = new TimerTask() {           
    @Override
    public void run() {                 
    }
};
timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000*60*4, 1000*60*4);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029040/how-to-run-an-android-app-in-background

Answer (score 1):

A service that runs for a longer period of time is only worth its execution (and energy consumption) time if it delivers value to the user continually. It's not the case of a location poller, which only delivers value for short periods of time, depending on what you do with the polled location. In this case you should implement a service that will perform a short task (I mean task in the general sense, not a `Task` object) and then you must schedule your service to run from time to time. You can use Android's scheduling mechanism, called [AlarmManager](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/2651), to schedule your services.

There is a problem inerent to this approach, though: when the system is in battery-saving sleep state, your service has to acquire a wake lock in order to execute properly, then when finished release the wake lock for the system to go back to sleep state. Implementing this wake lock acquisition/release mechanism is not a trivial task.

I suggest you to use Commonsware's [Location Poller](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) implementation instead of implementing one yourself. It is well tested and solves the issue of acquiring/releasing a wake lock for your service to execute in the background.

If you insist in doing the polling yourself (e.g. to put already written code to use), I recommend using Commonsware's [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) in order to avoid writing your own wake lock acquisition/release mechanism for your service. It's very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution for long running tasks is to use an [Android Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

> A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use. Each service class must have a corresponding  declaration in its package's AndroidManifest.xml. Services can be started with Context.startService() and Context.bindService().

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help. Upvotes and accepts help me and others who may have the same question in the future ^.^