# Android acceleromter in service

Tags: android, csv, accelerometer

First of all sorry to repost the question as I didn't post my code earlier just written some lines now I am failing to explain.So posting the question again with codes.
 I have written a code that will log the acceleromter data and save the data in a csv file. What I need to do is I have to run the acceleromter in background as a service. So,I m done with writing the codes for 
1.running the accelerometer, 
2.shown the data in textbox, 
3.write the data in a csv file. 
 Things that are left is making it a service. I m giving the code below(Howfar I have done)

```
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class AccelerometerVaue extends Activity implements SensorListener {

    SensorManager sm = null;

    TextView xacc= null;
    TextView yacc = null;
    TextView zacc = null;
    TextView xorient = null;
    TextView yorient = null;
    TextView zorient = null;
    TextView text = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        xacc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xvalue);
        yacc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yvalue);
        zacc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zvalue);
        xorient = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xvalues);
        yorient = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yvalues);
        zorient = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zvalues);


    }



    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
        synchronized (this) {

            if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION) {
                xorient.setText("Orientation X: " + values[0]);
                yorient.setText("Orientation Y: " + values[1]);
                zorient.setText("Orientation Z: " + values[2]);
            }
            if (sensor == SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) {
//              Time now = new Time();
//              now.setToNow();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                Log.d("Time",currentDateandTime);


                xacc.setText("Accel X: " + values[0]);
                yacc.setText("Accel Y: " + values[1]);
                zacc.setText("Accel Z: " + values[2]);
                String res=String.valueOf(currentDateandTime+"#"+values[0])+"#"+String.valueOf(values[1])+"#"+String.valueOf(values[2]);

                Log.d("test", res);


                CSVWriter writer = null;
                try 
                {
                    //Log.d("check","pasla");
                    //Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/AccelData.csv",true), ',');
                String[] entries = res.split("#"); // array of your values

                writer.writeNext(entries); 
                //FileWriter
                writer.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                //error
                }
            }            
        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy) {
        String tag = null;
        Log.e(tag,"onAccuracyChanged: " + sensor + ", accuracy: " + accuracy);

   }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sm.registerListener(this, 
                SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION |
                SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        sm.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }    


}
```

So, now I need to run a background service which will keep taking accelerometer data in background and also keep saving into that csv file. How can I do this? One more I like to ask is it possible to take the acc data after a certain period of time? Suppose here I m logging all the data continuously which is huge and thew battery drain will be huge. So, I need to implemented the service in such a way so that it will run in background for 15mins and log the data for 10 seconds at the beginning of each minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just replied to a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174200/application-exit-to-keep-it-in-background-for-some-times/17175484#17175484) question.

You can use Android's scheduling mechanism, called [AlarmManager](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/2651), to schedule your services.

There is a problem inerent to this approach, though: when the system is in battery-saving sleep state, your service has to acquire a wake lock in order to execute properly, then when finished release the wake lock for the system to go back to sleep state. Implementing this wake lock acquisition/release mechanism is not a trivial task.

I recommend using Commonsware's [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) in order to avoid writing your own wake lock acquisition/release mechanism for your service. It's very easy to use. You will basically declare a class that extends the `WakefulIntentService` class and override its `doWakefulWork()` method. In that method you will poll for accelerometer data and write it to a file. I'll just let you down in the part of displaying the data in the screen, I don't know how to do that (I suppose you will have to perform a bind to the service though). <:)

Comment: AlarmManager for scheduling, but first I would like to start the service implementation for my code. Suppose I am starting the service for an infinite time.I will manually stop the service later. How to do that? Not getting the right way to do that

Comment: I believe you can do that if you have an Activity responsible for scheduling/canceling services in `AlarmManager` and keep a reference to the same `PendingIntent` you used to perform the scheduling within the application (for example as a global static variable). You will need to provide that reference to `AlarmManager` when you intend to cancel a previously scheduled service.