# How can i make my app to work in background?

Tags: android

How can i make my app run in background ?
If it closes the screen nothing should change, and if the screen is on also it doesn't change.
I want to be able to recognize my voice when is on onPause().

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029040/how-to-run-an-android-app-in-background

Comment: `Android Services` are for same purpose. App running in the background with full functions as in foreground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need a **background service** but there are few types of [services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), read this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and decide what is your requirement, and what type of service you will need. Mainly there are two types of services `Service` and `IntentService`, both are almost same.

One other thing, system can kill service if it need resources, so, there is a solution which is **foreground service**, you can also use that.

> A [foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) service is a service that's considered to be something
>   the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system
>   to kill when low on memory