# How can I make my android application run in background

Tags: android, android-studio, background-application

I have developed an application which take image from front camera after every 30 seconds. When I press the back button my application stops. I want to run my application in background and I have no idea how to do it.
Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IntentService. It runs on a background thread and is not affected by UI lifecycles. You can reach about how to use it [here in the Android Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should read these documents about [**Services**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) on Android.and put those codes on what you need to be run on background as a service.that's all.

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.
>   Another application component can start a service and it will continue
>   to run in the background even if the user switches to another
>   application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service to
>   interact with it and even perform interprocess communication (IPC).
>   For example, a service might handle network transactions, play music,
>   perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the
>   background.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the following links below.

Another Stack Overflow question asking the same thing: [How to run an android app in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029040/how-to-run-an-android-app-in-background)
Android Development Documents for running background services: http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html

Hope this helps.