# volley json cache image doesn't work offline

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, caching

Hello i'm beginner in anroid. I created navigation drawer and fragments. I can getting data from json with url. It's working while online. But phone when offline i'm getting "unable to resolve host" error. I want to get data from url with json while offline. It's not caching
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR6TG.png)

fragment

```
private static final String jsonUrl = "http://sunumsitesi.com/json.php";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Urun> urunList = new ArrayList<Urun>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_yemek, container, false);
    return root;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View v = getView();
    if(v!=null)
    {
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.yemekList);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), urunList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        JsonArrayRequest urunReq = new JsonArrayRequest(jsonUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
            {
                hidePDialog();
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Urun urun = new Urun();
                        urun.setUrun_adi(obj.getString("urun_adi"));
                        urun.setUrl("http://www.iremdeveci.com/ornekler/resimler/resim.png");//example
                        urunList.add(urun);
                    } catch (JSONException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        AppController.getmInstance().addToRequestQueue(urunReq);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}
private void hidePDialog()
{
    if(pDialog!=null)
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog=null;
    }
}
```

and CustomListAdapter(extend BaseAdapter)

```
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Urun> urunItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();
public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity,List<Urun> urunItems)
{
    this.activity=activity;
    this.urunItems=urunItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return urunItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location)
{
    return urunItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (inflater==null)
    {
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,null);
    }
    if (imageLoader==null)
    {
        imageLoader=AppController.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();
    }
    NetworkImageView urunResim=(NetworkImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.urunResim);
    TextView urun_adi= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.urun_adi);
    Urun u = urunItems.get(position);

    urunResim.setImageUrl(u.getUrl(),imageLoader);
    urun_adi.setText(u.getUrun_adi());
    return convertView;
}
```

LruBitmapCache.java

```
public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize()
{
    final int maxMemory=(int)(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024);
    final int cacheSize= maxMemory/8;
    return cacheSize;
}
public LruBitmapCache()
{
    this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
}
public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes)
{
    super(sizeInKiloBytes);
}

@Override
protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value)
{
    return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight()/1024;
}

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
{
    return get(url);
}

@Override
public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap)
{
    put(url,bitmap);
}
```

Comment: how to get data from URL while offline? That's the question?

Comment: @Ulrich it's need to be cached while online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your pictures(http://www.iremdeveci.com/ornekler/resimler/resim.png) seems to be cached correctly as the have etag and cache headers.

However the very first request you make (http://sunumsitesi.com/json.php) doesn't seems to return neither cache headers nor etag. Thus you have the error you dont even reach the picture part.

You can either fix that from the server or make Volley cache it all, for which you need to create custom request and override

```
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
```

You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406399/load-local-data-if-internet-connection-not-available/36413200#36413200).

In your code this would be smth like

```
        JsonArrayRequest urunReq = new JsonArrayRequest(jsonUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
        {
            String dosyakonum = "http://www.pukkaliving.concept.com/upload/galeri/buyuk/";
            hidePDialog();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
            {
                try
                {

                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Urun urun = new Urun();
                    urun.setUrun_adi(obj.getString("urun_adi"));
                    urun.setUrl("http://www.iremdeveci.com/ornekler/resimler/resim.png");//example
                    urunList.add(urun);
                } catch (JSONException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            try {
                String jsonString =
                        new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Cache.Entry entry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
                entry.ttl = now + 30l * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;  //keeps cache for 30 days
entry.softTtl = now + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;  //will not try to refresh for 1 day     
                    return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString), entry);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                } catch (JSONException je) {
                    return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
                }
            }
        };
        AppController.getmInstance().addToRequestQueue(urunReq);
```

however for NetworkImage view you have to customize [ImageLoader](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/android-n-preview-1/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java) as this is the one creating the image requests and then the logic is the same. You have to override "makeImageRequest".

ex:

```
  ...
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache()) {
    @Override
        protected Request<Bitmap> makeImageRequest(String requestUrl, int maxWidth, int maxHeight,
                    ScaleType scaleType, final String cacheKey) {
                return new ImageRequest(requestUrl, new Listener<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                        onGetImageSuccess(cacheKey, response);
                    }
                }, maxWidth, maxHeight, scaleType, Config.RGB_565, new ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        onGetImageError(cacheKey, error);
                    }
                }){
          @Override
                    public Response<Bitmap> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        Response<Bitmap> resp = super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
                        if(!resp.isSuccess()) {
                            return resp;
                        }
                        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        Cache.Entry entry = resp.cacheEntry;
                        entry.ttl = now + 30l * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;  //keeps cache for 30 days
                        return Response.success(resp.result, entry);
                    }

        };
            }
};
    ...
```

Comment: Is there a simple example of this ?

Comment: check the link in the answer

Comment: If you will not help do not engage

Comment: .. i thought i was helping and the link provides an example... anyway I added to the response how this will apply to you code exactly. I hope now I am helpful...

Comment: well this should return 1 response and 1 error the response being intermediate. this is why probably u still get an error. the solution is to ignore the error even if the response is not final (i.e. coming form the cache) or add entry.softTtl = now + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; (as I did in the edited answer) which will not even try to refresh the cache thus no error will be received

Comment: i added the code nothing has changed. i searched and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628062/android-offline-request-with-volley  this page

Comment: well you can simply use the volley cache and it works perfectly fine. I do it myself this way. Are you sure you made a request while online at least once after changing the code?

Comment: Yes. first start getting images and text while online,next login internet will not be necessary

Comment: sry changed in the answer "30l" beacause it was truncated ti int.max. now it should work

Comment: thanks for your help.now it's work. Text okay. But image not loading.

Comment: there could be some caching issues with images as well so you can override makeImageRequest in Image loader to make sure we always cache. i updated the answer

Comment: Will it be still in fragment?

Comment: the code should be in you imageloader or whenever u initilize it so probably in thi singleton u have

Comment: I updated to question and i added LruBitmapCache.java. 
I benefit from this article : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

I can't override these methods in fragment or LruBitmapCache .

Comment: LruBitmapCache doesn not really affect the actual diskbased cache of Volley they are different things. I updated my answer to work with the example from the link you used. you need to add this to the initialization of ImageLoader in AppController.getImageLoader

Comment: onGetImageSucces and onGetImageError says: has private access in volley.toolbox.imageloader

Comment: I added this to gradle compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'. Not showing error. But same problem, text okay image not loading. img : http://i.hizliresim.com/qMnmgq.png

Comment: updated entry.ttl = now + 30l * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;  for image loader also

Comment: you are awesome my friend. now it's working exactly as I want. Thanks for  all your help!

Comment: few days later i tried this answer. it's not working offline

Comment: well if you exceeded your cache limit the cached could be trimmed

Comment: that's all for now : http://i.hizliresim.com/bD17l0.png and i will add more items.How much max cache and is there a solution ?

Comment: this seems to go a little off topic and adressing other issues than purely caching http responses. you can summarise your other needs and questions in another question as these comments and possible solutions they describe will be difficult to trace and find