# Accessing cached Images from LruCache Implementation

Tags: android, android-volley, android-lru-cache

I have a GridView with images and i have populated it using Volley and cached the images using the below links. I want to access the selected image of GridView in a new activity from the cached implementation. I have searched here on StackOverflow but could not find how to access the cached images using their key(int this case the URL). i have followed these links but couldn't find anything:

[Jake Whartons Volley CUstomization](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache)

[VolleyImageCacheExample](https://github.com/rdrobinson3/VolleyImageCacheExample)

Do I have to use the same LruCache object created in ImageLoder object in the second activity or is there any other way?

**Imageloader object in Singleton class**

This is the default implementation of LruCache object used. If someone could explain using the code below?

```
imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<>(10);

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return cache.get(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            cache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });
```

Assuming that i have a custom class BitmapCache that extends LruCache and implements ImageCache, please guide me how can i access the cache in 2nd activity to access the images cached

```
public class LruCacheClass extends LruCache<String,Bitmap> implements ImageLoader.ImageCache {

public LruCacheClass(int maxSize) {
    super(maxSize);
}



@Override
protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
    return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight();
}



@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    return get(url);
}

@Override
public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {

    put(url, bitmap);

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733589/how-to-cache-a-networkimage-to-use-in-another-activity-using-volley)

The reason was that i had resized the ImageView while getting the image from cache. Cache only returns the image that has the size that of the originally saved.